# How to apply SmartLifeCycle on the Multiple ProducerFactory

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, lazy-loading, spring-kafka

I'm planning to add the SmartLifeCycle on the Producer factory to fail fast, As I'm facing some issues in connecting to Kafka due to some server issues. So I'm planning to fail the applicatioin in the start itself, if there is any issue in connecting the Kafka cluster.

Is there any way I can add the SmartLifeCycle in a way that I should not touch the my existing code and apply SmartLifeCycle on Multiple ProducerFactory Objects.